# How to create multi-server sockets on one client in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, connection, multiserver

How to create multi-server sockets on one client in Python ?
I am thinking about create a List of server socket and make the connection with
non-blocking socket, but i don't find a good tutorial for that, thats why i came here,
to ask for better solution or a guide for non-blocking socket.

Thank you !

---

Thank for the help, but i mean to something different, i have list of Servers Ip like that:

SERVER_IP = ['127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.2', '127.0.0.3', '127.0.0.4', '127.0.0.5', '127.0.0.6, '127.0.0.7']

I have one option to create a list of sockets by ip, and try to connect to every Ip Server, but i ask
here if i have a different way to connect to all this  Servers Ip without a list of sockets, something more convenient.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have multiple sockets connected to multiple servers, you should check out the `select` module (http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html).

Basically, it works like this:

```
import socket, select
socks = {}
# Connect to different servers here #
sock1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socks[sock1.fileno()] = sock1
poll = select.poll()
for sock in socks:
    poll.register(sock)
while 1:
    fd, event = poll.poll() # Optional timeout parameter in seconds
    sock = socks[fd]
    sock.recv(1024) # Do stuff
```

A note, the `poll.poll()` method returns the underlying file number (what your operating system uses to represent files) which is useless to you. I just stores the sockets in a dictionary by that number so you could get the actual socket object from the filenumber that is given by poll. I recommend reading the documentation for select.poll, the link above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `select`. 
http://pymotw.com/2/select/ plus the `select` documentation. 
Or some third party module such as `twisted`.